# Show that the solution to $y^{''}+f(y)y^{'}+g(y) = 0$, where $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ and $g\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, is unique.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

The problem is:

> Show that the local solution to $y^{''}+f(y)y^{'}+g(y) = 0$, where $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ and $g\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, is unique.

Since my class currently has only covered the existence and uniqueness theorem of 1st order ODE, I think I should transform it into a system of 1st order ODE. Let $x_1 = y$ and $x_2 = y^{'}=x_1^{'}$. Then the DE becomes
$$
 x_1^{'}= x_2   \enspace \text{ and } x_2^{'} =   - f(x_1)x_2 -g(x_1).
$$
Define $F(x,y) =  (y, -f(x) y-g(x) \,)$. The DE now can be written as
$$
   \frac{d\psi}{dt}(t) =  F(\psi(t)), \, \text{where }\psi(t) = (x_1(t), x_2(t)), 
$$
which is a 1st order ODE. The function $F$ is continuous, hence given an initial condition, a local solution must exist. In order to show that it's unique, I think I should show that $F$ is Lipschitz. But it seems that $F$ needs not be Lipschitz. Setting $g \equiv 0$, and consider any $f$ that's continuous but not Lipschitz. Then for any points whose second coordinates coincide, $(x_1,x_2),(y_1,x_2)$, we have
$$
||F(x_1,x_2) - F(y_1,x_2)|| = |x_2| \cdot | f(x_1)-f(y_1)|.
$$
Since $f$ is not Lipschitz, $F$ also can't be Lipschitz from the equation above. Where do I get wrong? Can anyone prove the uniqueness of the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another use for $F$, the primitive $F(x)=\int_0^xf(s)ds$. Then the first-order system
$$
y'=v-F(y),~~~ v'=y''+f(y)y'=-g(y)
$$
is $C^1$ in both equations